# How to solve numpy error while installing mxnet?

Tags: python, windows, numpy, mxnet

I was just running the default command to install mxnet on Windows but this error popped up. I need to use mxnet in order to run insightface library. I was wondering what I did wrong.

What I've done:

- clean install of python 3.8
- downgrading my Python to 3.6.5 (doesn't work)

Python: 3.8.2
CUDA toolkit: 10.1

I ran:

```
pip install mxnet-cu101
```

```
Collecting mxnet-cu101
  Using cached mxnet_cu101-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (385.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from mxnet-cu101) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: graphviz<0.9.0,>=0.8.1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from mxnet-cu101) (0.8.4)
Collecting numpy<1.17.0,>=1.8.2
  Using cached numpy-1.16.6.zip (5.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet-cu101) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet-cu101) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet-cu101) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet-cu101) (3.0.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m6fnv3bf\\numpy_8eca072617e943b3ae46a61e83ecf95f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m6fnv3bf\\numpy_8eca072617e943b3ae46a61e83ecf95f\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ve4duj2p'      
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m6fnv3bf\numpy_8eca072617e943b3ae46a61e83ecf95f\
  Complete output (264 lines):
  Running from numpy source directory.
  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m6fnv3bf\numpy_8eca072617e943b3ae46a61e83ecf95f\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py:476: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
    return is_string(s) and ('*' in s or '?' is s)
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 
'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  blis_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
  get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
  customize GnuFCompiler
  Could not locate executable g77
  Could not locate executable f77
  customize IntelVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable ifort
  Could not locate executable ifl
  customize AbsoftFCompiler
  Could not locate executable f90
  customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable DF
  customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efl
  customize Gnu95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable gfortran
  Could not locate executable f95
  customize G95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable g95
  customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
  customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efort
  Could not locate executable efc
  customize PGroupFlangCompiler
  Could not locate executable flang
  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 
'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 
'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m6fnv3bf\numpy_8eca072617e943b3ae46a61e83ecf95f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  blas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m6fnv3bf\numpy_8eca072617e943b3ae46a61e83ecf95f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  blas_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m6fnv3bf\numpy_8eca072617e943b3ae46a61e83ecf95f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 
'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_clapack_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib       
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib      
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs      
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs     
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib       
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib      
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs      
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs     
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib       
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs      
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib       
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs      
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 
'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m6fnv3bf\numpy_8eca072617e943b3ae46a61e83ecf95f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m6fnv3bf\numpy_8eca072617e943b3ae46a61e83ecf95f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown 
distribution option: 'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building py_modules sources
  creating build
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\distutils
  building library "npymath" sources
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
  Running setup.py clean for numpy
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m6fnv3bf\\numpy_8eca072617e943b3ae46a61e83ecf95f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m6fnv3bf\\numpy_8eca072617e943b3ae46a61e83ecf95f\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m6fnv3bf\numpy_8eca072617e943b3ae46a61e83ecf95f
  Complete output (10 lines):
  Running from numpy source directory.

  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
Failed to build numpy
```

Comment: It looks like you need a compiler installed as the package is trying to build some libraries from source. I'd suggest following the advice in this part of the error message, and see if that gets you any further...
"""
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
"""

Comment: it is installed now, but it gave me this error FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\mxnet\libmxnet.so' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

Comment: thank you so much for the info, btw i fixed the last problem by moving the files from my CUDA to my mxnet library and it works fine now

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you're using pip, the latest available version of MXNet on Windows is 1.8. So I found that you can install this version of MXNet with `numpy==1.23.5`.

So running these commands worked for me:

```
pip install numpy==1.23.5
pip install mxnet -f https://dist.mxnet.io/python/cpu
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with you. My reason is I uninstalled anaconda but not clearly. My anaconda environment is messy. Packages are installed somewhere else. So my solution is to uninstall it clearly then install it again.  there is a package to clean anaconda, you may google it.

If you uninstall anaconda manually, you also need to uninstall python.
Maybe you could also create a new anaconda enviroment. it might hlep

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it tries to build the numpy package. The workaround would be to install it first with conda and specify the version of numpy from your error message, here 1.16.6:

```
conda install numpy=1.16.6
```

Then you can try installing mxnet again:

```
pip install mxnet-cu101
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is elementary and it's just a matter of incompatibility. mxnet has its own functions to handle arrays called  nd_array which then conflict with some of the parts of the NumPy arrays addition to that there are other problems so what you can do is install the latest  mxnet library and compatible numpy library which is as follows

Save this answer.
I think that if you're using pip, the latest available version of MXNet on Windows is 1.8. So I found that you can install this version of MXNet with numpy==1.23.5.

So running these commands worked for me:

pip install numpy==1.23.5

pip install mxnet -f https://dist.mxnet.io/python/cpu
as mentioned in the last answer.