# ERROR: Cannot install gluonts, mxnet, numpy and pandas because these package versions have conflicting dependencies

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mxnet-gluon

I wanted to install certain packages:

```
pip install gluonts==0.8.0 mxnet~=1.7 pathlib==1.0.1 numpy==1.17.2 pandas==1.0.5 ujson==4.0.2 torch~=1.6 pytorch-lightning~=1.1
```

But during installation, i got the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot install gluonts==0.8.0, mxnet==1.7.0.post1, mxnet==1.7.0.post2, numpy==1.17.2 and pandas==1.0.5 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
The user requested numpy==1.17.2
gluonts 0.8.0 depends on numpy~=1.16
pandas 1.0.5 depends on numpy>=1.13.3
mxnet 1.7.0.post2 depends on numpy<1.17.0 and >=1.8.2
The user requested numpy==1.17.2
gluonts 0.8.0 depends on numpy~=1.16
pandas 1.0.5 depends on numpy>=1.13.3
mxnet 1.7.0.post1 depends on numpy<1.17.0 and >=1.8.2
```

I was referring the following site for these installations:
https://business-science.github.io/modeltime.gluonts/articles/managing-envs.html

Is there a way to get all these packages installed wihtout any kind of dependency conflicts (even if it has to be within a new python environment such as `pipenv myenv`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install numpy 1.16.6 to be compatible to mxnet 1.7.
Since there are no binary (whl) files for numpy 1.16.6 for python greater than 3.7 you need a compiler to build numpy from source (a zip file). See also [how to solve numpy error while installing mxnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65325177/how-to-solve-numpy-error-while-installing-mxnet)

Or use python 3.7 instead with numpy 1.16.6 and mxnet 1.7